# How to get UIView frame origin and size while animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have UIView animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:25]; 
myview.frame = CGRectMake(218, 216, myview.frame.size.width * 0.5, myview.frame.size.height * 0.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and NSTimer with callback method. The question: is it possible to get current myview.frame size and origin inside timer callback method?
or may be there is another way to trace it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>I'm pretty sure that it's not possible, because when you change the `frame` of your view it takes effect immediately.  In the background, `Core Animation` takes care of the animation.  So, even if you could grab the frame, it'd give you the final coordinates, not the current coordinates in the midst of an animation.</strike>

Access the presentation layer of the property, as pointed out by `NWCoder` in the comments. See the [**documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer).

```
[view.layer.presentationLayer frame]
```

Comment: If anyone still needs this, it is possible. You can use: [[v.layer presentationLayer] frame];

Comment: I can confirm the use with swift:
view.layer.presentation()!.frame - will get the current frame while the view is animated.

Answer (score 2):

NWCoder is right.  I will give you an example in C# since I code in MonoTouch.

```
   RectangleF start = new RectangleF(0,0,100,100);
   RectangleF end = new RectangleF(100,100,100,100);
   UIView yourView = new UIView(start);

   UIView.Animate (120d, 0d, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, delegate {
    yourView.Frame = end;
   }, delegate { });
```

The code block above will move yourView from 0,0 to 100,100 in 120 seconds.  The moment the animation starts, yourView.Frame is already set to (100,100,100,100)...so yourView.Frame.X will equal 100 for the entire 120 seconds.

On the other hand, if you use the first line below any time during the 120 seconds...

```
   float currentX = yourView.Layer.PresentationLayer.Frame.X
   float currentProp = yourView.Layer.PresentationLayer.Frame.<any other frame property>
```

...you are in business.  You will get the live frame properties while animating.

Works great.  I'm using it in my app now.

Comment: @sudo voted me down...because I voted him down...not because my answer was incorrect.  Rather childish.  sudo's answer was incorrect and deserved a down vote.

Comment: Sorry, just happened to see your comment. I did not downvote your answer at all. Please don't assume things on other people like that.

Comment: I didn't have to assume anything.  You updated your post the very minute my answer got a down vote.  Coincidence?  Doubtful.

Comment: Didn't get that notification either. :/ I did not down vote your question. I have only ever given 23 down votes, and those were to legitimately terrible answers. I've never down voted out of spite, nor have I ever down voted competing answers. I can only assume that my edit caused the page to be bumped back up on the list of active questions, and someone visiting this happened to down vote your answer as a result. You might try looking at the best in people instead of jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

The view's frame is not updated during animation, as you have figured out.  You could try `myview.layer.frame` (just a guess, though I suspect that will not work either).

Comment: Actually, myview.layer.frame worked fine for me, as suggested above by Brian.