# Cropping a (UIGraphicsImageContext) image with a floating UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

Here is my view hierarchy: I have a view (default viewControllher's _view) in a Xib with a UIWebView subView in it. On the same Xib file, a separate second view (not inside _view) called floatView. The floatView gets added  programmatically on top of the UIWebView and can be dragged by user. Inside floatView I have a smaller subView (cropView).
I want to use cropView as a crop-frame to get the visible portion webView under it.

Heres the code I'm trying to use to do it, but the result is not what I need.

```
- (IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender {

    CGSize layerSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layerSize);

    [self.webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    [floatView convertRect:cropView.frame toView:self.view];

    CGRect CropFrame = cropView.frame;


    CGImageRef subImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CropFrame);
    UIImage *subViewImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImageRef];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(subViewImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

The image I get in camera roll is i cropped image with the right size not in the right position of the visible webView.

I have looked at other posts and solutions but can´t find one that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (kinda). Moved floatView inside _view hierarchy, o top of the webView and managed to get its origin coordinates with the [view.layer presentationLayer].frame  solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422500/how-to-get-uiview-frame-origin-and-size-while-animation). Now it works...