# how to get the current position of image view during animation in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get UIView frame origin and size while animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422500/how-to-get-uiview-frame-origin-and-size-while-animation)

```
 -(void)anothertarget1
{


    UIImage *uranus=[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-ball1.png"];


    imagev=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 100, 100)];
    imagev.alpha=0.6;
    imagev.image=uranus;

    [self.view addSubview:imagev];




    CGPoint goal = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x+70,self.view.center.y+24);

    CGPoint center=imagev.center;
    NSLog(@"center=%f",center);



    UIViewAnimationOptions opt = UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:20 delay:0 options:opt animations:^{
        //forimageview1;
        imagev.center = goal;


    } completion:^(BOOL f) {
        imagev.hidden=YES;

    }];

}
```

i want to make an object which get the current position of `UIImageview` during animation 
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a CADisplayLink, that updates the displayrate.