# Tracking UIView frame change animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiview

I have a UITextView that changes it's frame with the `animateWithDuration:animations` method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    [_textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height-25)];
}];
```

Is there any callback that helps me track the height of the UITextView as it animates?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't.  What are you trying to do exactly?  You may have to calculate the height based on how much the height is changing and the time it's taking to change.

Comment: Don't do that! The Easing function is not always linear and thus this approach won't be working. Either make a custom animation or see my answer.

Comment: Why are you looking for a way to track the frame of the text field during animation?

Answer (score 3):

There is no accurate way.
That's because the frame is just set directly. The animation takes care of the transition, but actually there is no transition.

There are some ways of estimating what is the current frame size and for me, the best is the simple math solution using a timer, when the animation started and the animation duration.

But, again, it's probably for the best if you just go another way, as this is certainly going to impact on your code cost and precision.

It's my first post and I don't really know anything that well, just learning and trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want to do with this thing.

If you want somehow accurate information about your frame, use the `presentationLayer`. This is a semi-accurate representation of what's actually on the screen. Note that this is in the coordinates of the view (bounds), so you need to convert it to the superview's coordinate system to get the current frame.

```
CGRect currentTextViewFrame = [_textView.superview convertRect:[_textView.layer.presentationLayer frame] fromView:_textView];
```

Note however this will be about one drawing loop or more off. If you are trying to base another animation off this it may be problematic and can cause flickering or other delay-induced effects. Also, at least the official documentation says this may not always be very fast and you may want to make the animation yourself if you need this information often due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
[_textView.layer.presentationLayer frame].size.height;
```

Credit belongs to [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422500/how-to-get-uiview-frame-origin-and-size-while-animation?answertab=oldest#tab-top).